# how to extract data from a mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a giant mysql including several databases on a server; 
I am connected by ubuntu to the server.

I login to the server by

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It shows all the databases that I have . then I take the one that i need

```
use mydatabase;
```

Then I see what tables I have

```
show tables;
```

Now I want to extract one of the tables on my desktop , how can I do this ?
Note that the server is connected through network

I also have a specific table and i want to add user to it
I get the table like this

```
select * from user_mine
```

it shows me somethinig like this

```
---------------------------
username  |  user_ID
---------------------------
user1     |ADMIN
user2     |ADMIN
--------------------------
```

I want to add user3| ADMIN

how can i do it?

Comment: [The simplest form of SELECT retrieves everything from a table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/selecting-all.html)

Comment: extract the data to show what ? csv ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: @Panther to get a csv with all info

Comment: @steeldriver can you please check whether you can help me to add a user into that table too?

Comment: @Moh these really aren't questions "about Ubuntu" - I suggest you refer to one of the many online tutorials, for example [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual: Loading Data into a Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html)

Comment: The link I gave you has several options to export to csv. You are starting to ask for basic mysql commands, I suggest you see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/ , https://www.elated.com/articles/mysql-for-absolute-beginners/ , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial and similar

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to extract one of the tables on my desktop , how can I do this ? Note that the server is connected through network

From Ubuntu command line (not SQL command prompt):

```
mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} {table} > export.sql
```

This will create a file "export.sql" with the table definition  and table content in it *in SQL format*. The '--no-create-info' will not export the table information, only data. You can also use it like this:

```
mysql -B -u {user} -p {database} -e "SELECT * FROM {table};"  | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > export.csv
```

to create a CSV file.

And then use ssh to copy export.sql or export.csv to your desktop.

> I want to add user3| ADMIN

```
insert ignore into user_mine (username, user_id) values ('user3','ADMIN');
```